# Counting Keys in Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose I have a Python dictionary like such:

```
{'To Kill a Mockingbird': ('Fiction', 11.99, 89), 'Killing Lincoln': ('Nonfiction', 15.99, 85), ... }
```

How can I add make a new dictionary by adding up the types of fiction and nonfiction books.

I will start with a empty dictionary like this:

```
temp = {'Fiction': 0, 'Nonfiction': 0}
```

In other words, assuming I have 5 fiction books and 17 nonfiction books, I want something like

```
newTemp = {'Fiction': 5, 'Nonfiction': 17}
```

I am a little confused about accessing the keys in seeing how they match up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = {'To Kill a Mockingbird': ('Fiction', 11.99, 89), 'Killing Lincoln': ('Nonfiction', 15.99, 85)}
dic = {'Fiction':0, 'Nonfiction':0}
for index, value in a.items():
    if value[0] in dic.keys():
            dic[value[0]]+=1

print(dic)
# output  {'Fiction': 1, 'Nonfiction': 1}
```

or other way

```
 from collections import Counter
 a = {'To Kill a Mockingbird': ('Fiction', 11.99, 89), 'Killing Lincoln': ('Nonfiction', 15.99, 85)} 
 sol = Counter(map(lambda x:x[0], a.values()))
```

Comment: This requires knowing all possible values of "type" in advance, to initialize `dic`.

Answer (score 2):

The strings you want to count are not keys - **titles** of the books are keys in your dictionary. Types are part of values. And counting them is easy:

```
from collections import Counter
dct = {'To Kill a Mockingbird': ('Fiction', 11.99, 89), 'Killing Lincoln': ('Nonfiction', 15.99, 85) }
c = Counter(x[0] for x in dct.values())
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {'To Kill a Mockingbird': ('Fiction', 11.99, 89), 'Killing Lincoln': ('Nonfiction', 15.99, 85)}
cnt = {}
for val in x.values():
    cnt[val[0]] = cnt.get(val[0], 0) + 1

print(cnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the keys from a dictionary via dict.keys()  And you can compare a key by iterating the keys with an if statement like

```
testkey = 'book title'
allkeys = dict.keys()
for k in keys():
    if k == testkey:
        #You have a match
```

Although strings don't test well, so you could learn how to use regular expressions, which adds a very powerful tool to your tool set.

The right way to do this the way you want is to test against an regular expression as such.

```
import re
booktitle = 'book one'
#Using above code
for k in allkeys:
    if re.match(booktitle,k):
        #You have a key match based on title
        #Do something
    else:
        #Case where there is no match
```

Hope that helps!

You can review those functions here. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_dictionary.htm

You can iterate an dictionary by the keys or by the items.